# Sufficient condition to say strict increasing function?

Tags: analysis

I have an arbitrary function $F(x)$. All I know about this function is that 
$$F'(x_1)>0,\;F'(x_2)>0,\;F''(x_1)>0$$ where $x_1<x_2$

Is this sufficient enough to say that function $F(x)$ is increasing $\forall \, x \in[x_1,x_2]$? If it is not sufficient, what else do I need to show?

Comment: No, it's not sufficient, you have no idea how the second and first derivatives are behaving within that range.

Comment: It is true however that $\forall x\in [x_1,x_2] . f'(x) > 0 \Longrightarrow f$ increasing on $[x_1,x_2]$ (but not the converse, consider $f(x) = x^3$ and any interval containing $0$).

Answer (score 3):

It is not sufficient, since we don't know whether there is a $c \in [x_{1}, x_{2}]$, s.t. $f'(c) < 0$. The $f''(x_{2})$ doesn't change anything about that. You need to show that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [x_{1}, x_{2}]$. From the given information alone you cannot show this. But if you were to show that $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, this would be sufficient.

Comment: Minor correction: even $f''(x) \geq 0$ would be sufficient.

Comment: thx for the remarks.

Comment: I think you applied my remark incorrectly. Since we want a strict increasing function, $f'(x) > 0$ (strict inequality) is required, but showing $f''(x) \geq 0$ is what would be sufficient, since we know the first derivative is already greater than zero at $x_{1}$, the second derivative could be zero for all in the range, and we're fine.